# Why is nginx taking so long to reply?

Tags: nginx, ddos

I'm under a DDOS attack right now, and the attacker has his zombies sending POST requests to one of my pages. At first, nginx replies in only a few seconds, but after a while it starts building up; nginx is taking 10 minutes to finish the responses to these requests! But why? I can't understand why. I can't even figure out why I can't stop it.

I've got these set:

```
    client_header_timeout 5;
    client_body_timeout 5;
    keepalive_timeout 5 30;
    send_timeout 5;
```

So should it not be timing out after 5 seconds? Why does it continue to 600 seconds or more? Is there a way I can figure out what type of attack this is? Slow header? Slow POST? How can I detect what this attack is and how can I stop it?

It should also be noted that the connections are passing through a load balancer and a Squid Cache reverse proxy, so the only way I can read the clients' true IP is through specific HTTP headers

Comment: Did you analyze Nginx's `error.log` ?

Answer (score 1):

It will be hard to figure it out like this; I would suggest a full packet tcpdump of one of DDoS sources and then analyze what he is doing in wireshark or some other tool for inspecting captured data.